# how to add an item to the method of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to add `bar` into the `items` array.

```
let myObj = {  
  item:_ => ['foo']
}
```

Tried doing this:

```
myObj.item().push('bar')
```

but when i do `console.log(myObj.item())` i get back `['foo']`
Any reasons for this behaviour ?

Comment: Yeah, it is how it works. Your function returns `['foo']`, each time you call it. Because you implemented it this way.

Comment: if you want an array then just write `let myObj = {item:['foo']}` , no need for a method to add an array as property.

Comment: Any reason for using `item:_ => ['foo']` instead of `item: ['foo']`? Seems like you have an *XY problem* here.

Comment: 3 years later and I'm laughing at myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let myObj = {  
   item: _ => ['foo'] // you make a new function called item that ALWAYS returns an array called foo
}
```

`myObj.item().push('bar')` actually pushes bar to the array returned by the function `myObj.item()`. But this is not persisted. Next time you call `myObj.item()` you would still get ['foo'] since that is what the function returns.

If you want to push directly to item array, create item as an array with initial value ['foo'] like so.

```
let myObj = {  
   item: ['foo'] 
}
```

Then you can do `myObj.item.push('bar');`

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not being updated instead you are pushing 'bar' into an array returned by your method and you can consol log that returned array in this way..

```
        let myObj = {
            item: _ => ['foo']
        }

        let arrayInAir = myObj.item();
        arrayInAir.push('bar');
        console.log(arrayInAir);
```

You can decide what your item method will return (evaluate to) before it returns something.So use this.

```
        let myObj = {
            what: ['foo'],
            item: _ => myObj.what
        }
        myObj.what.push('bar');

        console.log(myObj.item());
```